# Python error 1064 on mysqlconnector Create Statement

Tags: python, mysql, mysql-python, mysql-connector

I am attempting to create a small database where the user can at will create a new database to store information.

I am trying to take the users input and run a CREATE DATABASE IF NOT EXISTS, however I appear to be running into a problem where I get a 1064(42000) error.

Specifically it reads:

> mysql.connector.errors.ProgrammingError: 1064 (42000): You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use new ''test_client'' at line 1.

I have a separate class which is called build that is specifically used to create a database or a table at the request of the user.

The issue here is that I have one method of code that works and another that does not. I am trying to learn what is causing this issue as I am trying to ensure that the code is protected from any sql injections.

I have tried to write the code in two ways:

1. The users input is stored in a variable called 'name'. 
   I have a piece of code that add's a '_' if there are any white spaces in the name. 
   I have a variable (called sqlFormula) which houses the code:
   These are both then run into a mycursor.execute.
   And this is where I get the error.

Code:

```
    name = re.sub("\s+", "_", name)
    sqlFormula = ("""CREATE DATABASE IF NOT EXISTS %s""")
    mycursor.execute(sqlFormula, (name,))
```

This is the version that yields the error.

2. The second way, which works is by doing the following:

```
    name =  = re.sub("\s+", "_", name)
    sqlFormula = """CREATE DATABASE IF NOT EXISTS %s"""%name
    mycursor.execute(sqlFormula)
```

This does not yield an error.

The partial codes that are involved in this part are below:

```
class Build():
    __slots__ = ['userentry', 'database']

    def __init__ (self, used_database, user_entry = None)
        self.database = used_database
        self.userentry = user_entry

    def create_database (self)
        mycursor = self.database.cursor()
        name = re.sub("\s+", "_", name)
        sqlFormula = ("""CREATE DATABASE IF NOT EXISTS %s""")
        mycursor.execute(sqlFormula, (name,))
        mycursor.close()

class Create()
    def Create_table():
        user_input = input("What is the name of the database to create?")
        #a separate variable called db is used to house the db connection.
        Build(db, user_input).create_database()


I expected that by using the variable name in a tuple and the %s placeholder, that it would work without any problem. However I just keep getting the error.
```

Comment: as i know `execute()` doesn't put value in place of `'%s'` when it is place for table's name or column's name. Probably for security reason. So finally you have query with `%s` which means syntax error.

Comment: you can only use placeholders for expressions, not database, table, or column names.

Comment: You need to do ordinary string formatting.

Comment: @furas and @Barmar thanks for the info. I thought that may be the case. Given this, would the first way of running the execute, where ```sqlFormula = """CREATE DATABASE IF NOT EXISTS %s"""%name```, protect against an sql injection of any sort?